# Array<object> in typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript

I wanna add an object to an array but I don't know how to declare a variable with the return type is `Array<object>`.

My example:

```
var obj = {
   'Prop name': 'Prop value'
};

document.body.innerHTML = typeof obj; // output: object

var arr: Array<object>; // error message: Cannot find name 'object'
arr.push(obj);
```

I've tried again with:

```
var obj: Object = {
   'Prop name': 'Prop value'
};

document.body.innerHTML = typeof obj; // output: object

var arr: Array<Object>;
arr.push(obj); // error message: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

How can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error is because it's `Object` (title case) not `object` (lower case)

The second error is because you've typed the variable, but not actually assigned an instance. Try:

```
var arr: Array<Object> = [];
arr.push(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

You miss initialization of `arr` array:

```
var obj: Object = {
   'Prop name': 'Prop value'
};

document.body.innerHTML = typeof obj; // output: object

var arr: Array<Object> = []; // MODIFIED
arr.push(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Object` or `any` instead:

```
var arr: Array<any>;
```